# XML namespaces in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to build a distance matrix using OpenStreetMap travel times in Excel. I'm using the YOURS API and a Google Maps API excel module as reference (http://oco-carbon.com/2012/05/17/a-google-maps-journey-time-function-for-excel/).

This is an example of the XML I'm trying to bring into Excel: http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=xml&flat=60.480398&flon=22.277206&tlat=60.402923&tlon=22.355558&v=motorcar&fast=1&layer=mapnik

Currently my VB code looks like this:

```vb
Function G_TIME(Flat As String, Flon As String, Tlat As String, Tlon As String) As Double
' Requires a reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0
' Draws on the stackoverflow answer at bit.ly/parseXML
Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP60
Dim myDomDoc As DOMDocument60
Dim timeNode As IXMLDOMNode

G_TIME = 0
On Error GoTo exitRoute
' Check and clean inputs
' Origin = Replace(Origin, " ", "%20")
' Destination = Replace(Destination, " ", "%20")
' Read the XML data from the Google Maps API
Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP60
' myRequest.Open "GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" _
'    & Origin & "&destination=" & Destination & "&sensor=false", False
myRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=kml&flat=" & Flat & "&flon=" & Flon & "&tlat=" & Tlat & "&tlon=" & Tlon & "&v=motorcar&fast=1&layer=mapnik", False
myRequest.Send
' Make the XML readable usign XPath
Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument60
myDomDoc.LoadXML myRequest.responseText
' Get the time node value
Set timeNode = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Document/traveltime")
'If Format = "Decimal" Then ' Return as a decimal - 30 mins as 0.5 hrs
'    G_TIME = timeNode.Text ' Seconds in an hour
'Else 'Return in Excel's 00:00:00 date format - 30 mins as 00:30:00
    G_TIME = timeNode.Text ' Seconds in a day
'End If
exitRoute:
' Tidy up
Set timeNode = Nothing
Set myDomDoc = Nothing
Set myRequest = Nothing
End Function
```

I think the problem is here:

```
Set timeNode = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Document/traveltime")
```

The YOURS XML uses Google Earth KML style and it needs to be defined for Excel. I've tried to use the XmlNamespaceManager but I can't get it working. I suppose I need to import something but I'm not familiar with VB for Excel so I don't know where to do it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue with default namespaces when using XPath queries with Microsoft's DOMDocuments. You need to give the default namespace a prefix and then use that prefix in the XPath query - like this:

```
Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument60
myDomDoc.loadXML myRequest.responseText
myDomDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:r='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0'"

' Get the time node value
Set timeNode = myDomDoc.selectSingleNode("//r:Document/r:traveltime")
```

More info on this can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288147)